# Transpose data frame group wise using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with three columns containing the id, a feature name and the value. For id I have different features in different rows. Example:

```
df1  <– data.frame(id = c("A","A","A","B","B","B"), name = c("f1","f2","f3","f1","f2","f3"),value = c(1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 1.2,2.2, 3.2)))

#>   id    feature value
#> 1  A     f1      1.1
#> 2  A     f2      2.1
#> 3  A     f3      3.1
#> 4  B     f1      1.2
#> 5  B     f2      2.2
#> 6  B     f3      3.2
```

I want to rearrange the data and collect all observations (features) for one id in one row. My want my result to look like this:

```
#>   id  f1  f2  f3
#> 1  A 1.1 2.1 3.1
#> 2  B 1.2 2.2 3.2
```

If the data frame consists of only one id the data frame could be transposed using

```
df2 <-  t(df1)
df2 <- data.frame(df2) 
colnames(df2) <- df1$feature
```

Question: How can I transpose the data group wise to get the desired data format using dplyr? Any help is appreciated! Thx

Comment: This isn't a transpose. You should look up how to go from long data to wide data in R. Here is a link I reference: http://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape.html

Comment: Use `library(tidyr);spread(df1, name, value)`

Comment: sorry for the duplicate and thx for pointing me to the right solution :)